# Word lookup code optimization

Tags: java, optimization, search, lookup

I have a Java class which accepts some data and reads it in as a raster of characters x by y. The class is used then to look for occurrences of a certain word in any direction of the raster and store them in a multidimensional array.

My code works, but I would like to see the code optimized because to me it looks too cumbersome with all the `if`-`else`'s.

```
...
private static final int NORTH = 0;
private static final int NORTH_EAST = 1;
private static final int EAST = 2;
private static final int SOUTH_EAST = 3;
private static final int SOUTH = 4;
private static final int SOUTH_WEST = 5;
private static final int WEST = 6;
private static final int NORTH_WEST = 7;

/** The raster <code>char[yIndex][xIndex]</code> */
private char[][] raster;

/**
 * Starts looking through the raster to find occurrences of the given word.
 * @param word the word to look for
 */
public void searchWord(String word) {
    if (!searched || !this.word.equals(word)) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = 0;
        int w = raster[0].length, h = raster.length;
        for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
            for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
                this.occurrences = (int[][][]) ArrayUtils.addAll(
                    this.occurrences, 
                    search(x, y, w, h, toLowerCase(this.word.toCharArray())));
                    // toLowerCase is a helper method which converts a char array 
                    // to lower case characters
                this.count = this.occurrences.length;
            }
        }
        searched = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Looks at a given index in the raster for the occurrence of a word to 
 * <code>lookFor</code>.
 * The word is searched horizontally, vertically and diagonally, forward and reverse.
 *  
 * @param x start looking at this x-coordinate
 * @param y start looking at this y-coordinate
 * @param w width of the raster
 * @param h height of the raster
 * @param lookFor characters of the word to look for
 * @return the occurrences found for this word:
 *         int [occurrenceIndex][characterIndex][x,y coordinate] 
 */
private int [][][] search(int x, int y, int w, int h, char [] lookFor) {
    int len = lookFor.length, occurrences[][][] = new int [8][len][];
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                occurrences[j][0] = new int [] {x, y};
            } else {
                occurrences[j][i] = new int [] {-1, -1};
            }
        }
    }
    boolean north = y - (len-1) >= 0,
            east  = x + len <= w,
            west  = x - (len-1) >= 0,
            south = y + len <= h,
            northEast = north && east,
            northWest = north && west,
            southEast = south && east,
            southWest = south && west;
    for (int i=0; i<lookFor.length; i++) {
        if (north && raster[y-i][x] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[NORTH][i][0] = x;
            occurrences[NORTH][i][1] = y-i;
        } else {
            occurrences[NORTH] = null;
            north = false;
        }
        if (northEast && raster[y-i][x+i] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[NORTH_EAST][i][0] = x+i;
            occurrences[NORTH_EAST][i][1] = y-i;
        } else {
            occurrences[NORTH_EAST] = null;
            northEast = false;
        }
        if (east && raster[y][x+i] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[EAST][i][0] = x+i;
            occurrences[EAST][i][1] = y;
        } else {
            occurrences[EAST] = null;
            east = false;
        }
        if (southEast && raster[y+i][x+i] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[SOUTH_EAST][i][0] = x+i;
            occurrences[SOUTH_EAST][i][1] = y+i;
        } else {
            occurrences[SOUTH_EAST] = null;
            southEast = false;
        }
        if (south && raster[y+i][x] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[SOUTH][i][0] = x;
            occurrences[SOUTH][i][1] = y+i;
        } else {
            occurrences[SOUTH] = null;
            south = false;
        }
        if (southWest && raster[y+i][x-i] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[SOUTH_WEST][i][0] = x-i;
            occurrences[SOUTH_WEST][i][1] = y+i;
        } else {
            occurrences[SOUTH_WEST] = null;
            southWest = false;
        }
        if (west && raster[y][x-i] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[WEST][i][0] = x-i;
            occurrences[WEST][i][1] = y;
        } else {
            occurrences[WEST] = null;
            west = false;
        }
        if (northWest && raster[y-i][x-i] == lookFor[i]) {
            occurrences[NORTH_WEST][i][0] = x-i;
            occurrences[NORTH_WEST][i][1] = y-i;
        } else {
            occurrences[NORTH_WEST] = null;
            northWest = false;
        }
    }
    int [][] compareTo = new int[lookFor.length][];
    for (int i=0; i<lookFor.length; i++) {
        compareTo[i] = new int[] {-1, -1};
    }
    ArrayList<int[][]> items = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
    for (int [][] dirArray : occurrences) {
        if (dirArray != null) {
            items.add(dirArray);
        }
    }
    return (int[][][]) items.toArray(new int [][][] {});
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could theoretically make it nicer by introducing `Iterator<>` concept into the code. It would make your code more optimal from readability point of view but I doubt it would make the code more optimal from execution speed point of view. Your `Iterator<>` interface derivates would always move to the next character in given direction. Basically, the `ifs` would be hidden behind the iterators.

If using `Iterator<>` seems too heavy, you could abstract the position increments and direction into an array of (spatial) vectors. E.g., iteration increment in the north direction could be represented by `i * {0, +1}`. This way you could transform the `if/else` chain into iteration over an array of such vectors.

I would also introduce a class for the point/coordinate instead of using two element array.

All of this could improve the abstraction and readability. It is up to you to decide if it is worth it though.

Comment: could you give an example of how I would implement the spatial vectors, I tried this already but it didn't go as expected